# is it possible to draw something using canvas then view it in image view as a jpeg or any other image format?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-canvas

so I have created a canvas of an image and drawn over it using the function `canvas.drawCircle( 250F, 150F, 15F, paint)`
but the problem is that I can no longer zoom in or zoom out using a class that I made.
so I was wondering if it is possible to make the canvas into an image after drawing that circle so that it would make it easier to implement the zoom class.

Comment: What do you consider to be an image? And is your shift key missing?

Comment: You could view it in `ImageView` as a `Bitmap`